# Strange Rails behavior with custom mime types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, ruby-on-rails-4, mime-types

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1 and I am trying to implement an API with a custom mime type. That is, in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` I register an alias as like the following:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias 'application/json', :my_json
```

From another system I am trying to access the API with `curl` by running a HTTP PUT request, this way:

```
curl http://www.my_api.org/articles.my_json --request PUT --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary '{\"key\": {\"a\": \"1\", \"b\": \"2\"}}'
```

However, by inspecting the `ArticlesController` parameters in my Rails application, I get the following output (note: `article` parameters are "unwanted" and those duplicate the "wanted" `key` parameters):

```
Parameters: {"key": { "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2" }, "article": { "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2" }}
```

What is the problem? Is it a bug? How can I solve that?

---

Note: I have implemented and access other similar API by executing HTTP GET requests and all works as expected. The problem seems to happens only when I execute HTTP PUT requests.

Comment: sounds familiar. i have seen such type of question earlier also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @rafaelfranca - No it is not a bug. It is how `wrap_parameters` works. You can disable at this file in your application `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`.

See [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16043).